# Android Listview ViewHolder different items react together

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

I'm working on a ListView which use an Adapter and ViewHolder component in aim to ensure stability of items but I'm facing an unexpected behavior.

At first I need to explain that my items aren't static : each item is a row with a checkbox and when the box is checked a form appears below to ask user to give more informations.

But at the moment when user check the box and enter some text in the form, another item react the same way :

- checkbox checked
- the same text in the form

The unwanted reacting item is not drawn at the same time ( both items aren't visible together, a scroll is needed to see one or the other)

It's not accurate but my activity setting windowSoftInputMode is adjustNothing

Thanks for any answer!

Great day

Comment: Obviously problem is in your code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
private List<Object> mObjects;
private LongSparseArray<Account> uAccounts;

ImageView illustration;
TypefaceTextView explanation;
ProgressBar load;
ListView lv;

private Context context;
private AccountExpListAdapter accountExpListAdapter;
public int occurences;
private boolean allGood = true;

private void initUI() {
    if (getActivity() != null && getActivity().getApplicationContext() != null) {
        accountExpListAdapter = new AccountExpListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                mObjects);
        if (lv != null) {
            lv.setAdapter(accountExpListAdapter);
        }
    }
    if (load != null)
        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView logo;
    TextView tv;
    RelativeLayout header;
    RelativeLayout form;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    EditText email_ET;
    EditText pwd_ET;
}

public class AccountExpListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {


    private List<Object> objects;
    private Context context;


    public AccountExpListAdapter(Context context, List<Object> objects) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (vi == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selectable, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.logo = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.logo);
            holder.tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.header = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.header);
            holder.form = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.form);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.box);
            holder.email_ET = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.email_edit_text);
            holder.pwd_ET = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.pwd_edit_text);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        final Object object = objects.get(position);

        Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse(object.getLogo())).into(holder.logo);
        holder.tv.setText(object.getName());
        final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
                manageKeyboard(isChecked);
                int visibility = isChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
                finalHolder.form.setVisibility(visibility);
                if (!isChecked) {
                    uAccounts.remove(object.getId());
                } else {
                    uAccounts.put(object.getId(), new Account());
                    allGood = false;
                   lv.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position + 1, 150, 500);
                    finalHolder.email_ET.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
        holder.header.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finalHolder.checkBox.performClick();
            }
        });
        if (holder.form != null) {
            holder.email_ET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    if (!checkEmailFormat(editable.toString())) {
                        finalHolder.email_ET.setError(getString(R.string.email_invalid));
                        allGood = false;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        allGood = true;
                    }
                    Long objectId = object.getId();
                    Account a;
                    if (uAccounts.indexOfKey(objectId) < 0) {
                        a = new Account();
                    } else {
                        a = uAccounts.get(objectId);
                    }
                    a.setUsername(editable.toString());
                    uAccounts.put(objectId, a);
                }
            });
            holder.pwd_ET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    if (editable.toString().length() == 0) {
                        finalHolder.pwd_ET.setError(getString(R.string.password_invalid));
                        allGood = false;
                        return;
                    } else {
                        allGood = true;
                    }
                    Long objectId = object.getId();
                    Account a;
                    if (uAccounts.indexOfKey(objectId) < 0) {
                        a = new Account();
                    } else {
                        a = uAccounts.get(objectId);
                    }
                    a.setEncrypted_password(editable.toString());
                    uAccounts.put(objectId, a);
                }
            });
        }
        return vi;
    }
}
}
```

the code is quite complex for the checkbox due to the show/hide form but does it may produce this unwanted listview items behavior?

Thanks